# Get only text value where user click it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Get only text value where the user clicked it

**HTML code**

```
<body>
    <div id="test">
        <pre>
        zelketg  1
        gcaotydv  14
        cdbot_i 11
        pacdhss12  1
        boters  1
        <pre>  
    </div>
</body>
```

In the above code I am using `pre` tag, I have a long list of user so I want every user on next line

When the user click on `zelketg`, only I want `zelketg` under javascript alert box instead of whole text.

I tried the below JavaScript but it didn't works, It give me the whole text under `div`

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
    var text = $(event.target).text();
    alert(text);
});
```

Comment: `$('#test').text()`

Comment: Share a working snippet to demonstrate your effort/issue.

Comment: why you can use a dropdown instead of pre tag?

Comment: @gurvinder372 I tried the event bubbling concept, but I am a getting full text under `pre` tag

Comment: @compsy Sure, lets see your code. By sharing a working snippet, you will get help a lot faster.

Comment: In order to do what you want, you're going to have to add a mouse event, and then do some calculation on your own to analyze what word was clicked. Not impossible, but quite tricky. You'd be better off breaking each thing into a separate element.

Comment: Instead of using `pre` you have to moderate your string to proper displayed values like a table or other set of elements. Other vises you have to use a complex way with the clicked position of the document and return full line of code where the event is fired.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Contents of pre tag are not identifiable as an individual nodes, so you need to do some **pre-conditioning** so that **they can be identified as an individual nodes**.

```
var preNode = document.querySelector( "pre" );
function preCondition()
{
  var text = preNode.innerText;
  preNode.innerHTML = text.split("\n").map( s => "<div>" + s + "</div>" ).join( "" );
}
preCondition();
```

Now you can add a click event handler on the *`pre`-tag*

```
preNode.addEventListener( "click", function(){
  console.log(event.target.innerHTML);
});
```

**Demo**

```js
var preNode = document.querySelector( "pre" );
function preCondition()
{
  var text = preNode.innerText;
  preNode.innerHTML = text.split("\n").map( s => "<div>" + s + "</div>" ).join( "" );
}

preCondition();
preNode.addEventListener( "click", function(){
  console.log(event.target.innerHTML);
});
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <pre>
        zelketg  1
        gcaotydv  14
        cdbot_i 11
        pacdhss12  1
        boters  1
   </pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Its work perfectly fine, Thanks for this awesome solution

Answer (score 1):

Try as follows might help

```js
$(document).click(function(event) {
    var text = $(event.target).text();
    alert(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div id="test">
        <pre>
        <i>zelketg  1</i>
        <i>gcaotydv  14</i>
        <i>cdbot_i 11</i>
        <i>pacdhss12  1</i>
        <i>boters  1</i>
        <pre>  
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: can you try showing result without changing DOM elements ?

Comment: Why not go over all lines using jquery and add the `i` tag to each line beforehand. It should work then.

Comment: It gives the whole text, if user click outside the area

Answer (score 1):

Go over each line beforehand and turn them into `span` elements so you can handle them separately.

```js
var lines = $("#test pre").text().split("\n");
$("#test pre").empty();
$.each(lines, function(n, elem) {
    $("#test pre").html( $("#test pre").html()+'<span>'+elem+'</span><br>');
});
$('#test pre').click(function(event) {
    var text = $(event.target).text();
    console.log(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div id="test">
        <pre>
        zelketg  1
        gcaotydv  14
        cdbot_i 11
        pacdhss12  1
        boters  1
        <pre>  
    </div>
</body>
```

*Post-Fork of @Nisal Edu*

Answer (score 1):

You can replace your whole pre element as the following example for this you don't need any other library alike.

```
<body>
    <div id="test">
        <pre id="test_pre">
        zelketg  1
        gcaotydv  14
        cdbot_i 11
        pacdhss12  1
        boters  1
        </pre>  
    </div>
</body>

<script>
    function getText(elem)
    {
        var user_name = elem.childNodes[0].innerHTML;
        var user_id = elem.childNodes[1].innerHTML;
        alert(user_name+","+user_id);
    }
    (function(){
        var pre_tag = document.getElementById("test_pre");
        var pre_text = pre_tag.innerHTML;
        var pre_elem = pre_text.split('\n');
        var doc_string ="" ;
        for(item in pre_elem)
        {
            var arr = pre_elem[item].trim().replace(" ",",").split(",");
            doc_string += "<p onclick='javascript:return getText(this);'><span>"+arr[0] +"</span><span> "+ arr[1] +"</span></p>";       
        }
        document.getElementById("test_pre").innerHTML = doc_string;
    })();
</script>
```